# Different IP addresses, same interface

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi and I have configured the wifi interface with static IP - `192.168.0.110`. It worked fine, on every restart it got this IP.

But this beautiful morning I restarted the Pi and something strange happened this time. The router shows that the Pi has `192.168.0.105` for IP, while `ifconfig` shows wl0 - `192.168.0.110`.

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  
          inet addr:192.168.0.110
```

I DO NOT have a LAN interface plugged in, only wifi. And guess what - I CAN connect via SSH using both IPs 110 and 105.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: What does `ip route`say?

Comment: `default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  metric 303
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.105  metric 303`

Comment: ip route says indeed the IP address is 105. That is odd you also see 110 using ifconfig, and even more you are able to connect to both.